# Thunderbird profile in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: thunderbird

This seems like a very simple question. I want to move my Thunderbird profile from Windows to Ubuntu. Where exactly should I place the file in Ubuntu? Please give me the path to the folder where I would plug it in. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird profiles in Ubuntu are stored in the (hidden) `.thunderbird` folder in your home directory. You might have to enable showing hidden files in your Files manager to see it.

So you would copy your Windows Thunderbird profile (the folder is usually named `????????.default`) just into that directory.

Then you'll also have to copy the `profiles.ini` file to the same location too, and edit it to fix the changed path settings and make sure they fit the new Ubuntu location.