# Is it possible to transfer my configuration files to another installation?

Tags: files, configuration, email, thunderbird

I have been looking for a portable solution for a Mozilla Thunderbird app but unsuccessfully so far. It is vital for me to keep Thunderbird's configuration so after a fresh OS install, once I install Thunderbird again I would have all my email accounts connected to the thunderbird app and would not need to reconnect them again to the freshly installed Thunderbird package.

Now how can I do that? I am completely new to Linux and do not have a clue which files I should save in order to achieve my goal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thunderbird profile in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120458/thunderbird-profile-in-ubuntu-18-04) See also http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird. Really easy to find if you search.

Comment: It did not work. I I have copied all the contents from Thunderbird Portable/data/profile of my Thunderbird Portable Windows application to ~/.thunderbird/xxxxxxx.default of my Ubuntu installation, but it just did not work - when I opened Thunderbird my profile was not there.

Comment: You normally have to start Thunderbird which creates a default profile. Then edit profile.ini to use your profile not the default one just created. See links on profiles in links in first comment.

Comment: But the profile name is the same, since I left the same profile but replaced the contents of that profile with my old profile.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it doesn't work. I always copied the xxx.default folder into .thunderbird new.default and it worked. Not this time. I have no idea what is going on and why this was changed, but it's such a pain, I have 9 email addresses...